# Appending values to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking at the smartest way of using a dictionary to handle some data output. I have a unique key which will have associated it other values so for example we have 1:[2, 3, 4, 7], 2:[8, 9, 5]. What I'd like to do is to be able to append the values such that the for the first key I could add the number 13 and get the following:

```
1:[2, 3, 4, 7, 13], 2:[8, 9, 5]
```

Append does not seem the smartest way of doing this. I am using:

```
dict[master = dict[master].append(id)
```

but I get the following:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Now I could simply take the previous values of they key and simply do the following (id = 17):

> newvalue = values, id

but this would lead to extra brackets such as

```
1:[[2, 3, 4, 7, 13], 17]
```

What is the smartest way of ensuring that I only get numbers in one set of brackets i.e.

```
1:[2, 3, 4, 7, 13, 17]
```

I could use some stripping functions - but is there a good easy way and simple way of doing this. I might be overlooking something simple here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `collections.defaultdict` (and, wottthehell, make each entry a `collections.deque` just for fun; you could also use a plain old `list` of course).

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

d = defaultdict(deque)   # or ...(list)

d[1].append(2)
d[1].extend([3, 4, 7, 13])
```

The basic idea here is that your dictionary values are *always* `deque`s and you *always* append to them, so you never have to worry about whether a value is an `int`. If you use a key that doesn't exist in the dictionary, `defaultdict` will create a new `deque` for you automatically, so you never have to check whether the key already exists in the dictionary either.

If you already have a regular dictionary with single `int` values -- say it was a return value for some function you called -- you can just use that dict to build up your new one, before using it for whatever you're doing with it.

```
d = defaultdict(deque)
for key, value in old_d.iteritems():
    d[key].append(value)
```

Comment: I was just typing up an answer for `defaultdict`, but you're too fast. +1

Comment: Thanks for that. That looks like the behaviour I'm trying to achieve. However all the machines we need to run on are Python 2.4, and I don't think defaultdict is available until 2.5. I'm working on the upgrade now...

Comment: Is there a smart way of using interitems with the defaultdict? Routines now don't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Lists are mutable. Just change it in place.

```
dict[master].append(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) Create a class to wrap this up (even better, use `defaultdict(deque)` in place of a `dict`, as suggested by @kindall; you only need a new class if you need more than that gives you)

(2) Use a `deque` as the value for *every* entry in your dict, even empty or single-value entries, and append to that deque. `deque` is intended to have constant-time appending at both ends; `list` is actually a vector.

Comment: I don't get the point of this answer at all.  Why should anybody write a custom class for something that is perfectly handled by the built-in classes?  Why should the OP use a `deque` if all he wants is appending at the end?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: As explained, deque provides constant time appending at the end, unlike list. He should wrap this up because his datastructure is not a dict - it is a dict which holds a list of objects. By creating a class, he can do things like ensure that the invariants he is relying on can be relied on. You know, the same reasons that we don't only use dicts for everything, but have classes too.

Comment: Lists do support (amortised) constant-time appending, so I still don't see the point of a `deque`.  Most certainly, a deque will be slower than a list for this application.  And I still don't think that the answer "Create a class to wrap this up" is helpful in any way (no offense intended).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: If you disdain normal software engineering practices, that's your problem. If you're certain that list will be slower, then maybe you could give some reasons. A scenario where there are a lot appends, no insertions, and access is by iteration over the whole structure is the *exact use-case for which deque is designed*.

Comment: Unless you need to support fast insertion at the beginning of the list, there is no benefit to using a deque over a list. If you need to access an interior element (not `L[0]` or `L[-1]`), deques (O(n)) are a worse choice than lists (O(1)).

Comment: I think a *deque* will be slower than a list, except for insertion at the *beginning*.  Appending at the end is [about the same speed for deque and list](https://gist.github.com/1627501).  All other operations that might occur will be faster for a list, in particular item access.  But all this isn't the reason why I think this answer misses the point.  The OP obviously struggles with using a dict of lists correctly.  I sincerely don't belive that the answer "Create a class to wrap this up" will be of any help to the OP.

Comment: @chepner: There is not any suggestion that random access is required. The reason I recommend a deque is because there will be a lot of additions at one end. That is what linked datastructures are for.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I'm seeing that deque is consistently slightly faster on my machine. I would expect the performance of deque to be more consistent, given that it's constant time, not amortised constant time. As to OP struggling with dicts of lists: *that is why it should be wrapped up in a class*. That is what classes facilitate: consistent reuse of code.

Comment: @Marcin: Out of interest, I tried a few different machines with different architectures, and I couldn't find any that has deque consistently faster than a list for appending. Moreover, when I [included the time for creation of the container and iterating it once](https://gist.github.com/1629659), deque was consistently slower on all machines; iterating the container once is the miminum you might want to do with it once created.